How can I force trigger MFA, when logging into Azure?
When using az login or MSAL, the user authenticates by signing into Azure (Entra ID).
How can I force MFA during sign in?
The reason I need this is that a custom conditional access policy denies tokens in OBO flows issued to an application, where the user signed in from a non-managed device without MFA. So, proactively triggering MFA will fix the issue

As a user account has been setup MFA enable in Microsoft Entra ID, When he az login in command line it will pop-up MFA notice. it's not the matter of az login but wheather you enable MFA or not in Microsoft Entra ID

The user must be enabled MFA in the Azure Portal

@wenbo Does Entra always require MFA, if it has been enabled for the user? Doesn’t it skip it, if it believes the sign in is safe, like origninating from corporate network?

Yes Entra requires MFA from corporate network too

@Rukmini Thanks for confirming. Can you refer to the docs? What confuses me is that if I start a new incognito browser session, then I can login to Azure without using MFA, using my username/password. It ask for permission to use a client certificate on my managed device, but no MFA, or does the client certificate count as MFA in this case?

@Rukmini Furthermore, signing in to Azure CLI (az login) is performed like above. The amr claim contains pwd and rsa, but no mfa. So, I'm definitely not prompted for MFA, despite MFA registered for my user and prompted for on unmanaged devices or using the device code flow


Note that: To force MFA, you need to enable MFA in Microsoft Entra ID either by conditional policy, security defaults or per user MFA.

I enabled MFA for the user via per user MFA:

Now I did az login:

Generated access token to check the amr claim:
az account get-access-token --resource https://management.azure.com/


The amr contains mfa claim successfully:

